# from Sqlite3 to Mysql in django chatbot website

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

i'ev developed a chatbot web application using Django and python3 on web faction server. Basically the chatbot interacts with a store's users as a customer server.It  uses the REST API to POST the user input and GET to display the chatbot output and a python file to process the input and find the output.

How the chatting works:

**1. chatboy.js:** it first POST the user input in the API then run the python file chabot.py.

**2. chabot.py:** a python file that connects to the Django backend db.sqlite3 and the conversation.sqlite3. So it select the user input from db.sqlite3 then select the matching output in the conversation.sqlite3. Finally the file will update the chatbot output in the db.sqlite3.

**3. chatboy.js:** will GET the last chatbot output and display it.

In development stage when i was testing the application in my local server everything works fine but problems came we i deployed the Django project in the internet. Mostly and the main ERORR that stops the application form working is :

```
    The database is locked
```

I did many research and found out that:

1. sqlite3 is not for production and only for small or stand alone application.
2. sqlite3 have a multiple threads problem.
3. not good for realtime chatting application.

Some suggestion said either

1. switch all the sqlite3 to Mysql ( but how? and how i can change the sql queries in the python file to fit Mysql)
2. use a fast key value store like Reddis ( does it mean to make it the backend db form my project or juts the conversation.sqlite3?)

please help me because it is very frustrating and i had this error for a long time and i couldn't found and solution for the problem.

thank you,

PS: i'm using Django 10 , python3 , sqlite3, web faction server

Comment: If you're using Django, you shouldn't need to change any queries; one of the big advantages of an ORM is that it's database agnostic.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for reply, so is it best to change the database form sqlite to mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update your settings file to change the DATABASES setting from sqlite3 to mysql or postgresql. But before you do that you will need to create a database in your Webfaction Control Panel (more information [here](https://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/databases.html)).